# LaTeX で label が機能してくれません

Tags: latex

LaTeXについての質問です．`\label`が機能してくれません．
環境：Mac 最新OS，エディタはAtom
プリアンブル：

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4j,uplatex]{jsarticle}
\usepackage{ascmac}
\usepackage[]{multicol}
\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}
```

経緯：
（マルチコラムが厄介者で，これを使うと写真が挟めないので，figureではなく，
下のようにfigurehereで対応しました．）以下のように\label{sample}をしても表示が「図を参照します。」となります．なぜでしょうか

```
\begin{document}
\begin{figurehere}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{imf.png}
\capion{imf} \label{sample}
\end{figurehere}\\

図\ref{sample}を参照します。

\end{document}
```

Comment: コマンドラインでコンパイルすると、「LaTeX Warning: Reference \`sample' on page 1 undefined」、「LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.」、「LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.」といったメッセージが表示されます。ソースファイルと同じディレクトリに生成される aux ファイル(`*.aux`)を見ると判るかと思いますが、`\newlabel{sample}{{1}{1}}` と書かれています。再度コンパイルすると、この定義が使用されますので、期待通りの結果を得る事ができます。

Comment: ご返信遅れてすみません．ご回答ありがとうございます．初心者なのでわからないのですが，再度コンパイルというのは具体的に何をすれば良いのでしょうか？何かコードを書き足す？

Comment: コマンドライン上では `uplatex src.tex` を実行するだけです。

Comment: ありがとうございます．すみません，コマンドラインとはどこで開けるのでしょうか？Logではないのですよね

Comment: Atom を使ったことがないので憶測ですが、「実行」とか「ビルド」などというメニューはありませんか？ つまり、初回に dvi ファイルを作成するのと同じ操作をすればよいのです。LaTeX のソースファイルを変更する必要はありません。

Comment: 普段プログラムを書いているところに書き込めばいいのですね

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます．やっぱりダメでした．それにエラーコードもでないという不思議な事態です